# To find total number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this

```
Table1
=======    

A                    B
8                    5
2                    9
null                 4
2                    5
```

How to find total number of rows from table1,note if any column value is null in a row then that row should be considered as 2 rows?

> I have tried with count(*)*2 and nvl function it doesn't work

Comment: Is there any possibility of using nvl here ?

Comment: `NVL()` just substitutes for `NULL` value.. `count()` will consider it as one row only...

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A IS NULL OR B IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS CountVal
FROM TABLE1
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5584b/2)**

O/P:

```
COUNTVAL
--------
5
```

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT()` is rowbased.. you can tweak it using `SUM()` instead..

```
select sum(NVL2(a,NVL2(b,1,2),2)) FROM TABLE1
```

`CASE` as suggested by @Vignesh is the simplest and more readable !!

COUNT() can also done like this.. But *NOT* a optimal solution at all!

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
(    
    SELECT NVL(a,NVL(b,1)) FROM TABLEA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NVL(a,NVL(b,1)) FROM TABLEA 
        WHERE A OR B iS NULL
)
```